# Apache mod_proxy with hostname

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I need to proxy the URL **http://de.domain.com/article1/foobar/** to **http://de.foobar.domain.com/article1/**.

I already have this config.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/foobar/$ http://de.foobar.domain.com/$1/
```

But I need to redirect the language in the URL too.
So I need something like

```
ProxyPassMatch http://([a-z]+).domain.com/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/foobar/$ http://$1.foobar.domain.com/$2/
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using the hostname is possible with the Proxy statements. You probably need to use the rewrite engine.

[Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

Comment: Can you post an example for my case? I didn't get a solution.